# Dice_loss for validation set

Tags: niftynet

I'm using `NiftyNet` to process `MRI` images. It seems that the main program has only two options:

1. train, to update weights based on training set;
2. inference, to predict.

I want to adjust my `hyperparameters` using `validation` set, is there any convenient way to calculate the `dice_loss` of the validation set? I know there's the dice_loss calculation function, but starting from there can be quite painful...

Any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To get an approximate idea, you can use the validation monitoring functionality. If you split the dataset into training, validation, and test (using either the `exclude_fraction_for_validation` and `exclude_fraction_for_inference` fields or by using a pre-defined `dataset_split_file` csv file), then you can calculate the batch-wise loss on the validation throughout training using the `validate_every_n` and `validation_max_iter` parameters.

In the next release (and the dev branch on the repo) there is a new action called evaluation, which lets you run calculate metrics (including Dice) on the output after inference

You need to add an [EVALUATION] heading to your config file, and use the evaluation action after running the inference action. It will create csv files in MODEL_DIR/evaluation with metrics for each subject and aggregated over the dataset.

By default, it assumes you want to evaluate on the test set (if you have used `exclude_fraction_for_inference` or `dataset_split_file`) or all data (otherwise). To use it for the validation set, (1) run inference with the extra parameter --dataset_to_infer=Validation, then (2) run evaluation with the extra parameter --dataset_to_infer=Validation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! Yeah I also noticed that maybe another function of this package would be needed for `Validation`. Right now I got around this problem with some dirty changes of applications, config file and the application driver. Looking forward to the update of NiftyNet!